# Deep Linking Android with special characters

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want my app to be opened on only one url that is in the form

http://www.myhost.com/topic#/line
http://www.myhost.com/topic#/line1

But I suppose special characters are not allowed in deep link urls. I have tried encoding # have used wild characters also but no help.
Please provide a solution to this.

Comment: It looks fine if you remove (or encode) the space char in the middle of the url

Comment: I have also tried encoding the "#" but it didn't worked.

Answer (score 3):

The `#` in a URL indicates the beginning of the [fragment component](http://uri.thephpleague.com/4.0/components/overview/), which cannot be used for deep link criteria. Even though you've structured the fragment to *look* like a normal URL path to human eyes, the computer does not read it this way.

You'll need to reformat your URLs not to include any `#` character before the path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the only solution was to remove the # from the urls and then do the deep linking.

Answer (score 0):

If you use &(ampersand) this is also can not be readed. You should use %29 instead